# Set model_pred_proba while using sklearn.metrics..roc_curve to evaluate anormaly detection model

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, roc

I want to evaluate model performance of anormaly detection using sklearn.metrics.roc_curve Since class 0 is anormaly data, I set pos_label parameters to 0.

But when draw roc_curve, it is strange.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESu2R.png)

So one thing I think as problem is Thresholds return of sklearn.metrics.roc_curve(), starts from 2. I think this is problem. When threshold is 1, My model estimate only 3 of 61 datas as probabilty 1, but it says tpr is 0.049 not 0.951 ( 0.951 is right because TP = 58, FN = 3 ).

output of roc curve using origin prob data.

```py
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
a = np.ones(y.shape[0])
y_pred_probaa = a - y_pred_proba
# fprs, tprs, thresholds = roc_curve(y, y_pred_probaa, pos_label=0)
fprs, tprs, thresholds = roc_curve(y, y_pred_proba, pos_label=0)


print(fprs)
print(tprs)
print(thresholds)
```

```
[0.         0.99756296 0.9983753  0.99918765 1.         1.
 1.         1.         1.         1.         1.         1.
 1.         1.        ]
[0.         0.04918033 0.08196721 0.3442623  0.52459016 0.55737705
 0.60655738 0.63934426 0.73770492 0.78688525 0.83606557 0.90163934
 0.93442623 1.        ]
[2.        1.        0.9921875 0.984375  0.9765625 0.9609375 0.953125
 0.9375    0.9140625 0.8828125 0.8515625 0.7421875 0.71875   0.6328125]
```

summarize my question, I think threshold should start from 0, because pos_label = 0 but sklearn doesn't. And my solution is recalculate probabilty as 1 - y_pred. Is this right solution?

When try this roc_curve is shown below picture.
[roc_curve_renew](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0iJJ.png)

My source code for 1 - y_pred.

```py
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
a = np.ones(y.shape[0])
y_pred_probaa = a - y_pred_proba
fprs, tprs, thresholds = roc_curve(y, y_pred_probaa, pos_label=0)
# fprs, tprs, thresholds = roc_curve(y, y_pred_proba, pos_label=0)


print(fprs)
print(tprs)
print(thresholds)
```

```
[0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00
 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00
 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 8.12347685e-04
 1.62469537e-03 2.43704305e-03 1.00000000e+00]
[0.         0.01639344 0.06557377 0.09836066 0.16393443 0.21311475
 0.26229508 0.36065574 0.39344262 0.44262295 0.47540984 0.6557377
 0.91803279 0.95081967 1.        ]
[1.3671875 0.3671875 0.2890625 0.28125   0.1875    0.1484375 0.09375
 0.0859375 0.0546875 0.046875  0.03125   0.0234375 0.015625  0.0078125
 0.       ]
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this information can help.

Actuall probabilty of data is reconstructed ratio.

This means, when probabilty is 0.9, 90% tokens are correctly reconstructed. I expect normal data has high ratio and anormaly data has low ratio.